# In Druid, how to do update datasource set metric1 = xxx, metric2 = yyy where dimension1 = zzz?

Tags: olap, druid

In  Druid, is it possible to do `update datasource set metric1 = xxx, metric2 = yyy where dimension1 = zzz` ?  and how？

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert based on a where clause that uses the dimension.
To overwrite the data you have 2 options: 
First is to make the changes to the original raw data and then re-ingest all the data set.
Second option is to add a delta to the existing data source http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/update-existing-data.html